# Change Genbank entry date with Biopython

Tags: sequence-analysis, biopython

I can create a new Genbank record in Biopython with the following code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO, SeqFeature
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_dna
from Bio.Alphabet.IUPAC import IUPACAmbiguousDNA

my_sequence = "ATAGGGACUCATAGATA"
my_record = SeqRecord(Seq(my_sequence, IUPACAmbiguousDNA()))
my_feature_location = SeqFeature.FeatureLocation(2,5, strand=1)
my_feature = SeqFeature.SeqFeature(my_feature_location, type="CDS", id="Cre")
my_feature.qualifiers["foo"] = "bar"
my_record.features.append(my_feature)

print my_record.format("gb")
```

The corresponding genbank file then looks like:

```
LOCUS       .                         17 bp    DNA              UNK 01-JAN-1980
DEFINITION  .
ACCESSION   <unknown id>
VERSION     <unknown id>
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      .
  ORGANISM  .
            .
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     CDS             3..5
                     /foo="bar"
ORIGIN
        1 atagggacuc atagata
//
```

How can I change this bit `UNK 01-JAN-1980`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the problem is that you are probably using wrong class for your record. Compare [Bio.SeqRecord class](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqRecord.SeqRecord-class.html) with [Bio.GenBank.Record class](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.GenBank.Record.Record-class.html). Reason why in your GenBank format you have this reference date (01-JAN-1980) is because your record has intrinsically no date attribute, so `SeqRecord.format` set undefined fields to default (look through the source code to see where this happens).

What you want to do for creating GenBank record is following:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
>>> from Bio import GenBank
>>> from Bio.GenBank import Record
>>> my_rec = Record.Record()
>>> my_rec
<Bio.GenBank.Record.Record object at 0x1030b1890>
>>> my_rec.sequence = Seq(my_sequence)
>>> my_rec.sequence
Seq('ATAGGGACUCATAGATA', Alphabet())
>>> print(my_rec)
LOCUS                         bp                                         
DEFINITION  .
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      .
  ORGANISM  .
            .
ORIGIN      
        1 atagggacuc atagata
//
>>> my_rec.date = '13-JUL-2015'
>>> my_rec.features.append(my_feature)
>>> my_rec.data_file_division = "ROD"
>>> print(my_rec)
LOCUS                         bp                    ROD       13-JUL-2015
DEFINITION  .
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      .
  ORGANISM  .
            .
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
type: CDS
location: [2:5](+)
id: Cre
qualifiers:
    Key: foo, Value: bar
ORIGIN      
        1 atagggacuc atagata
//
```

Notice, how `print(my_seq)` outputs data in GenBank format by default (since that is a GenBank record after all). I am sorry I cannot really talk on differences between `GenBank.Record` and `Bio.SeqRecord` and why/when use one object or another.

Anyways, looking up reference documentation is always a good habit: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.GenBank.Record.Record-class.html

Comment: have you tried the code you suggest? appending `my_record.date = "13-JUL-2015"` or `my_record.data_file_division = "ROD"` does not modify my resulting record.

Comment: Many thanks! As a follow-up question, do you know how I could actually save a `Bio.GenBank.Record` object? The `SeqIO.write(main_record, destination+".gb", "genbank")` I used before gives me `TypeError: 'Record' object is not iterable`. The obvious solution, `SeqIO.write([main_record], destination+".gb", "genbank")` gives me `TypeError: object of type 'Record' has no len()`...

Comment: Actually, I turned that into [a question in its own right](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36069/save-biopython-genbank-record-with-seqio-write).

Comment: For ``Bio.SeqIO.write(...)``` you have to give it ``SeqRecord`` object(s), it does not understand ``Bio.GenBank.Record`` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `SeqRecord` object approach with `Bio.SeqIO`, you would do something like this:

```
my_record.annotations["data_file_division"] = "PLN"
my_record.annotations["date"] = "24-DEC-2015"
```

Note that only valid NCBI GenBank divisions, or their EMBL equivalent, will be accepted.